# Render inverted scene to framebuffer

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, mirror

I need some help with rendering inverted scene to framebuffer. I want to make a mirror effect. 
What i have in result:
[image: My result]
Initializing frame buffer:

```
GLuint FramebufferName = 0;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &FramebufferName);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FramebufferName);

GLuint renderedTexture;
glGenTextures(1, &renderedTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderedTexture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST); 
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC, GL_LEQUAL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL_COMPARE_R_TO_TEXTURE);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderedTexture, 0);
glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);
```

Draw scene to frame buffer:

```
    mView = camera.getViewMatrix();
    mProjection = perspective(45.0f, 4.0f / 3.0f, 0.1f, 300.0f) * scale(mat4(1.0f), vec3(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f)); 
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, FramebufferName);
    glViewport(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    mWorld = rotate(mWorld, -15.0f, vec3(1, 0, 0));
    mWorld = rotate(mWorld, -30.0f, vec3(0, 1, 0));
    cubemap.Draw(mView, mProjection, mWorld);
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glUseProgram(program);
    mWorld = translate(mat4(1.0f), vec3(0, -10, 0));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(mvp_object, 1, GL_FALSE, value_ptr(mProjection * mView * mWorld * scale(mat4(1.0f), vec3(10.0f))));
    cannon.Draw(program);

    mWorld = mat4(1.0f);
    mWorld = translate(mat4(1.0f), vec3(50, -10, 0));
    mWorld = rotate(mWorld, 90.0f, vec3(0, 1, 0));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(mvp_object, 1, GL_FALSE, value_ptr(mProjection * mView * mWorld * scale(mat4(1.0f), vec3(10.0f))));
    cannon.Draw(program);

    mWorld = mat4(1.0f);
    mWorld = translate(mat4(1.0f), vec3(0, -10, 50));
    mWorld = rotate(mWorld, 140.0f, vec3(0, 1, 0));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(mvp_object, 1, GL_FALSE, value_ptr(mProjection * mView * mWorld * scale(mat4(1.0f), vec3(10.0f))));
    cannon.Draw(program);

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

I saw some tutorials where used glScalef(1.0, -1.0, 1.0) to invert scene. 
glScalef was used in old versions of opengl. How can i invert scene in new versions of opengl? 
I've multiplied projection matrix on scale(mat4(1.0f), vec3(1.0, -1.0, 1.0)) for this effect. Is it right?

Comment: "How can i invert scene in new versions of opengl?" e.g in the shader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the vertex shader written in GLSL.

```
void main(void)
{
   // Clean up inaccuracies
   vec2 Pos = sign(gl_Vertex.xy);

   gl_Position = vec4(Pos.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
   // Image-space
   gl_TexCoord[0].xy = vec2(-Pos.x, Pos.y) * 0.5 + 0.5; // x texture coord is inverted       
}
```

`Pos` refers to screen aligned quad for framebuffer output.

Fragment shader

```
uniform sampler2D framebufferSampler;

void main(void)
{
   gl_FragColor = texture2D(framebufferSampler, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
}
```

Screen aligned quad can be drawn

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS)
{
    glVertex2f(-1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex2f(1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex2f(-1.0f, 1.0f);
}
glEnd();
```

or using vertex arrays.

```
GLfloat vertices[] = {
    -1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f
};

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, (void*)vertices);

glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

texture that is used to be wraped to the quad, is the framebuffer info with previous rendered content (multipass shader technique).

You can also do so with others 2D texture coords or images instead of framebuffer and screen align quads.

Original image.

[image]

Inverted image.

[image]

More info can be found in [Learn OpenGL](http://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-OpenGL/Framebuffers).

Comment: I would say it's a pretty bad example, when you're using deprecated OpenGL. As it isn't even clear whether OP at all is using it.

Comment: @Vallentin: What you mean 'Deprecated'.

Comment: Deprecated like in it shouldn't be used and deprecated like in it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Deprecated means that it should be avoided and not used, and that it might be deleted in the future. `glVertex` and the like, doesn't work in later OpenGL versions, and is looked down upon.

Comment: @Vallentin: It is classic OpenGL, and as I know it would not be deleted as for hight performance graphics will be used VulkanAPI and OpenGL will go to rest. However if OP want to get best performance he could use vertex arrays and buffer objects as I said in my post.

Comment: The `glVertex` functions and the like, is deleted from OpenGL 3.1 and up. Also yes, Vertex Arrays and Buffer Objects is what should be suggested to OP or at least mentioned, and no your post doesn't mention it.

Comment: @Vallentin: 'or by using vertex arrays.' read my post carefuly. And what realisation of OpenGL do you use? Because standard must support all older versions. New versions of OpenGL is only an extension to older.

Comment: Welp, overlooked that. My point being that you can easily make non-backwards compatible OpenGL contexts, and since it's deprecated and has been for YEARS! That means that they could easily remove it in future OpenGL versions. Modern GPUs don't support the fixed-function pipeline anymore, but currently most do emulate it using shaders and whatnot.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But it seems to me we don't understand each other.
I don't need invert texture i need invert scene then write it to texture using frame buffer and show this texture on a plane for example.

Comment: @Vertigo: Every scene framebuffer can be used as texture, and can be palced on arbitrary surface.

Comment: @Vertigo: You can place the camera at arbitrary point. Read framebuffer content and place it to the texture. Than place the surface where you whant to display. Attach to it that texture. Than place the camera to proper position.